# Using Lodash or vanilla JS what is the most efficient way to filter an array based on object keys?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have two arrays of objects:

```
array1 = [
    {id:1, name: 'one'},
    {id:4, name: 'four'}
]

array2 = [
    {id:1, name: 'one'},
    {id:2, name: 'two'},
    {id:3, name: 'three'},
    {id:5, name: 'five'},
    {id:6, name: 'six'},
    {id:7, name: 'seven'}
]
```

I would like to remove any object from `array1` who's `id` **does not** exist in `array2`.

so my expect result would be:

```
array1 = [
    {id:1, name:'one'}
]
```

Comment: In other words, you want to find the intersection between two arrays? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript

Comment: Have you tried either approach yet?

Comment: What did you try that is not efficient?

Comment: What is the definition of "efficient" as used at Question? What are the benchmarks of the code that you have tried to resolve inquiry? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lodash's [`_.intersectionBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#intersectionBy):

```js
var array1 = [
    {id:1, name: 'one'},
    {id:4, name: 'four'}
];

array2 = [
    {id:1, name: 'one'},
    {id:2, name: 'two'},
    {id:3, name: 'three'},
    {id:5, name: 'five'},
    {id:6, name: 'six'},
    {id:7, name: 'seven'}
];

var result = _.intersectionBy(array1, array2, 'id');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

A fast and readable option would be:

```
var referenceKeys = array2.map(function(entity) { return entity.id; });

var result = array1.filter(function(entity) {
    return referenceKeys.indexOf(entity.id) !== -1;
});
```

But no guarantee that it's the fastest in all dimensions. (Number of repeats, length of array1, length of array2).

Comment: Depending on what is meant by "efficient" this may not be a good solution since it is quadratic.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a standard approach by using a hash table which uses just one iteration for both arrays.

```js
var array1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'one' }, { id: 4, name: 'four' }],
    array2 = [{ id: 1, name: 'one' }, { id: 2, name: 'two' }, { id: 3, name: 'three' }, { id: 5, name: 'five' }, { id: 6, name: 'six' }, { id: 7, name: 'seven' }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result;

array2.forEach(function (o) {
    hash[o.id] = true;
});

result = array1.filter(function (o) {
    return hash[o.id];
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Set` for this:

```
const seenIds = array2.reduce((set, o) => set.add(o.id), new Set());
const result = array1.filter(o => seenIds.has(o.id));
```

Comment: `const seenIds = new Set(array2.map(o -> o.id));` Just a little shorter. :)